# How to programmatically click a material element?

Tags: angular

I can programatically click a button element with elementref but if a button were of material button then it doesn't work

```
@ViewChild('findButton') findButton: ElementRef;
  clicked() {
  console.log('clicked');
}
ngOnInit() {
  this.findButton.nativeElement.click()
}
```

and in the template,

```
<div class="example-button-row">
  <button #findButton (click)="clicked()" mat-raised-button color="primary">Primary</button>
</div>
```

The mat-raised-button attribute is creating the issue. Here is the [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u6nf7y-kcnjhj?file=app%2Fbutton-types-example.ts) on stackblitz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the `ElementRef` associated with the `MatButton` with the following syntax:

```
@ViewChild('findButton', { read: ElementRef }) findButton: ElementRef;
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u6nf7y-gdevmp) for a demo.

Answer (score 3):

Use `MatButton` as its type instead of `ElementRef`

```
@ViewChild('findButton') findButton: MatButton;
clicked() {
  console.log('clicked');
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.findButton._elementRef.nativeElement.click();
}
```

Forked [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u6nf7y-r8cvu2?file=app/button-types-example.ts)

Comment: Thanks. I worry I could not accept more than one answer.